# Jacob to drag and drop Outlook Emails to java Swing

Tags: outlook-2010, jacob

I am using Jacob-1.18-M1 to Drag Drop the outlook emails on to a Java Applet. It works  perfectly fine with Outlook 2003, but fails with Outlook 2010. I get the “Operation Failed” message. Any help is greatly appreciated.